# How to set text in file (html input type)

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

How can we set text in html file uploader.

Is it possible using JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. The value attribute is ignored, and the DOM value property is readonly.

Otherwise `<input style="display: none" type="file" name="mine-now" value="path-to-some-common-sensitive-file">`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set this (security reasons - only user can select file in browser ), but if you need it you can clear this field using this script:

$get('FileUploadCtrlId').outerHTML="<input type=file style='WIDTH: 400px' id ='FileUploadCtrlId'>"